# Why can't I see all Position records created by users & other data access questions

Tags: force.com, data, role-hierarchy

It seems that users can only view/edit Position records that they have created. However, I expect records to be readable and editable by users higher in the Role Hierarchy. I also expect records to be readable but *not* editable by users lower in the Role Hierarchy. These are the Position records in existence and their owners:

- User C made a "Sales Rep" Position record
- User A made "Product Manager" Position record
- User B made an "IT Coordinator" Position record
- I made an "Intern" Position record

**Permission Sets**

- Hiring Managers (User A)

  - Position object permissions = CRE

**Profiles**

- Custom-Engineering (User A)

  - Position object permissions = R
- Custom-Executive (User C)

  - Position object permissions = CRED & View All
- Custom-Recruiter (User B)

  - Position object permissions = CRE
- System Administrator (myself)

  - Position object permissions = CRED, View All, & Modify All

**Roles (hierarchically)**

- CEO (User C)

  - Product Manager, under branch 1 (User A)
  - Recruiter, under branch 2 (User B)

**Security Controls > Sharing Settings > Positions**

- Default access = Public Read Only
- Grant Access Using Hierarchies = selected

Comment: Anybody with the standard System Admin profile can always see everything. Are you sure the other records exist? How have you tried to view them?

Comment: I can view them when I login as these individual users A, B, and C under Positions.

Comment: But when logged in as the System Admin how are you searching for them? Global/sidebar search? What if you run a report on the object set to "All Positions" and Created Date = All Time?